# How to unit test a DAO that is extending SqlMapClientDaoSupport

Tags: java, spring, ibatis, easymock

Spring DA helps in writing DAOs. When using iBATIS as the persistence framework, and extending SqlMapClientDaoSupport, a SqlMapClient mock should be set for the DAO, but I can't do it. SqlMapClientTemplate is not an interface and EasyMock cannot creates a mock for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAO and unit tests do not get along well !
That does not make sense to mock anything in a component that does not hold any business logic and is focused on database access.
You should try instead to write an integration test. Take a look at the spring reference documentation, chapter 8.3 : http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html

Comment: While I can see your logic, I can envisage DAO functionality that could benefit from unit testing. Therefore I don't think it's fair to say that DAOs should not be unit tested - it all depends on the class in question.

Answer (score 1):

This exact reason is why I don't extend from `SqlMapClientDaoSupport`.  Instead, I inject a dependency to the `SqlMapClientTemplate` (typed as the interface `SqlMapClientOperations`).  Here's a Spring 2.5 example:

```
@Component
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @Autowired
    public SqlMapClientOperations template;

    public void myDaoMethod(BigInteger id) {
        int rowcount = template.update("ibatisOperationName", id);
    }
}
```

Comment: And another reason why Composition is better than Inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

As @Banengusk suggested - this can be achieved with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). However, it is important to establish that your DAO will be using a Spring `SqlMapClientTemplate` that wraps your mock `SqlMapClient`. Infact, `SqlMapClientTemplate` delegates invocations to the `SqlMapSession` in the IBatis layer.

Therefore some additional mock setup is required:

```
mockSqlMapSession = mock(SqlMapSession.class);
mockDataSource = mock(DataSource.class);

mockSqlMapClient = mock(SqlMapClient.class);
when(mockSqlMapClient.openSession()).thenReturn(mockSqlMapSession);
when(mockSqlMapClient.getDataSource()).thenReturn(mockDataSource);

dao = new MyDao();
dao.setSqlMapClient(mockSqlMapClient);
```

We can then verify behaviour like so:

```
Entity entity = new EntityImpl(4, "someField");
dao.save(entity);

ArgumentCaptor<Map> params = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
verify(mockSqlMapSession).insert(eq("insertEntity"), params.capture());
assertEquals(3, params.getValue().size());
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4), params.getValue().get("id"));
assertEquals("someField", params.getValue().get("name"));
assertNull(params.getValue().get("message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). It lets mock classes, not only interfaces.