# Using Spring 4.0.9 with myBatis 2.3.5

Tags: java, spring, migration, mybatis, ibatis

I have a Project with framework **Spring 3.0.3**, **myBatis 2.3.5**. 
I want to migrate to **Spring 4.0.9**. The problem i am facing is spring have stopped supporting **myBatis** from **3.0.5**. The myBatis part is heaving used so cannot shift to **hibernate** or even **myBatis 3.x**. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: Spring 4.0.9 does not include **SqlMapClientDaoSupport** and this class is used extensively in my project for transaction. i just want to migrate the spring by keeping **mybatis** version same.

Comment: and if i upgrade the **mybatis** i have to change the mapping using a project http://mybatis.github.io/spring/ which will effect more than 1.6k files, which i do not intend to do

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106218/spring-replace-sqlmapclienttemplate-for-all-clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the ibatis package from [Spring 3.0.3.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v3.0.3.RELEASE). From the test results till now it is integrated nicely even the spring transaction is working good with it. Will be doing further testing and will post if it have any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the removed classes with this maven dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-2-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

We are using mybatis 2.3.5 with Spring 4.3.5 and it works fine.